# How to force nginx to give a response inline instead of download?

Tags: http, nginx

I am using the below recipe to provide nice fallback error message in case the backend server is down.

The problem is the response is downloaded as a file by the browser instead of being displayed as a HTML response.

```
 location @fallback {
        echo_status 504;
        add_header Content-Type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8";

        echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
        echo "<html lang='en'>";
        echo "  <head>";
        echo "    <meta charset='utf-8'>";
        echo "    <title>Backend is down</title>";
        echo "  </head>";
        echo "  <body>";
        echo "    Backend service is offline, please retry in few minutes. $echo_timer_elapsed";
        echo "  </body>";
        echo "</html>";
    }

    location / {
            error_page 502 504 = @fallback;
            proxy_connect_timeout   10s;
            proxy_pass              http://backend:8090;
            proxy_read_timeout      10800s;
    }
```

Comment: You need to send a Content-Disposition header.

Comment: I already found this, but I didn't see any option to force it not to download. What is the format?